# `.psqlrc` setting, but hide the debugging message that this setting has turned on

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14

I have configured `psql`, the PostgreSQL command line client, with `~/.psqlrc` file, and I have the line `\timing`, to show how long queries took. But `psql` will print a line telling me that it has applied that setting. Can I turn that off?

My current psqlrc:

```
$ cat ~/.psqlrc 
\pset pager off
\timing
```

which gives this output on my unix shell (bash):

```
$ psql -c "select version()"
Pager usage is off.
Timing is on.
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.1.0-8) 12.1.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

Time: 0.362 ms
```

I do not want the `Pager usage is off.` or `Timing is on.` messages to be printed. I want the `\pager …` and `\tim…` settings to be *quietly* applied.

e.g.: I want this output:

```
$ psql -c "select version()"
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.1.0-8) 12.1.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

Time: 0.362 ms
```

Is this possible?

---

I am aware of `-X`/`--no-psqlrc`. But I want the setting applied without a debug message:

```
$ psql -X -c "select version()"
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.1.0-8) 12.1.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

---

Software versions: psql 14.5, with postgresql 14.5, installed via latest (2022-09-20) apt on Debian testing/bookworm.

Answer (score 2):

Make the first line in the .psqlrc be

```
\set QUIET on
```

And presumably the last line to turn it back off again.